# Create react app with Css modules @import @value

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, css-modules

I'm using Create react app with css modules like stated [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet)

On my main.css file I have variables defined like this

```
@value BestColor: #c6a972;
```

and on my component.module.css file I use those variables

```
@value variables: "../../../index.css";
@value BestColor variables;

.aVeryNiceComponent {
    color: BestColor;
}
```

I'm using Typescript with TsLint on Webstorm. 
Is there any way to lint and check that the BestColor value exists and is making reference to the on index.css file?

Now is possible to add a new color like here, but the variable is non existent on index.css and fails silently.

```
@value variables: "../../../index.css";
@value BestColor, WhiteBG variables;

.aVeryNiceComponent {
    color: BestColor;
    background-color: WhiteBG;
}
```